# Accessing variables returned from perl: Dumper

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, data-dumper

I'm having problems accessing elements/arrays returned from perl Data::Dumper.  I'm able to access results such as these:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'head' => {
                'source' => {
                            'credit-logo' => 'foo',
                            'feedback' => 'bar',
                            'more-information' => 'google',
```

And with the following line, I can get the 'credit-logo' value:

```
$credit=        $result->{head}->{'source'}->{'credit-logo'};
```

However, I'm having trouble with the following, where the whole thing starts with a "[" instead of a "{":

```
$VAR1 = [
      'dwml',
      {
        'xmlns:xsi' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
        'version' => '1.0',
        'xmlns:xsd' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
        'xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation' => 'site'
      },
      [
        [
          'head',
          {},
          [
            [
              'product',
              {
                'concise-name' => 'time-series',
                'srsName' => 'WGS 1984',
                'operational-mode' => 'official'
```

In the above, how would I access the 'srsName' value?

No matter what I try, I get messages about the value not being a HASH or ARRAY.

--
My original script is trying to get forecast data from NWS:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use NDFD::Weather::Report;
use Data::Dumper;


$result=NDFD::Weather::Processer->new(

    listLatLon=>'30.3369,-81.6614',
    product=>'time-series',
    Unit=>'m',
    maxt =>0,
    mint =>0,
    temp =>1,
    dew =>1,
    pop12 =>0,
    qpf =>0,
    sky =>1,
    snow =>0,
    wspd =>1,
    wdir =>1,
    wx =>1,
    waveh =>0,
    icons =>0,
    rh =>0,
    appt =>0,
    incw34 =>0,
    incw50 =>0,
    incw64 =>0,
    cumw34 =>0,
    cumw50 =>0,
    cumw64 =>0,
    conhazo =>0,
    ptornado =>0,
    phail =>0,
    ptstmwinds =>0,
    pxtornado =>0,
    pxhail =>0,
    pxtstmwinds =>0,
    ptotsvrtstm =>0,
    pxtotsvrtstm =>0,
    tmpabv14d =>0,
    tmpblw14d =>0,
    tmpabv30d =>0,
    tmpblw30d =>0,
    tmpabv90d =>0,
    tmpblw90d =>0,
    prcpabv14d =>0,
    prcpblw14d =>0,
    prcpabv30d =>0,
    prcpblw30d =>0,
    prcpabv90d =>0,
    prcpblw90d =>0,
    precipa_r =>0,
    sky_r =>0,
    td_r =>0,
    temp_r =>0,
    wdir_r =>0,
    wspd_r =>0,
    wgust =>0

);
$value= $result->NDFDgenLatLonList;
$xml_handler1=$result->Parse_XML_Data_decode($value);


print Dumper $xml_handler1;
```

My goal is to extract the values returned from that Dumper response.

Here is the XML returned, by adding:  print $value;

--

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dwml version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.nws.noaa.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd">
<head>
<product srsName="WGS 1984" concise-name="time-series" operational-mode="official">
  <title>NOAA's National Weather Service Forecast Data</title>
  <field>meteorological</field>
  <category>forecast</category>
  <creation-date refresh-frequency="PT1H">2015-10-02T15:56:10Z</creation-date>
 </product>
 <source>
  <more-information>http://www.nws.noaa.gov/forecasts/xml/</more-information>
  <production-center>Meteorological Development Laboratory<sub-center>Product Generation Branch</sub-center></production-center>
  <disclaimer>http://www.nws.noaa.gov/disclaimer.html</disclaimer>
  <credit>http://www.weather.gov/</credit>
  <credit-logo>http://www.weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif</credit-logo>
  <feedback>http://www.weather.gov/feedback.php</feedback>
</source>
</head>
<data>
<location>
  <location-key>point1</location-key>
  <point latitude="30.34" longitude="-81.66"/>
</location>
<moreWeatherInformation applicable- >
<time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
  <layout-key>k-p3h-n35-1</layout-key>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-02T14:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-02T17:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-02T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-02T23:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T02:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T05:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T11:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T14:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T17:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T23:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-04T02:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-04T05:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-04T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-04T11:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-04T14:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-04T17:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-04T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-05T02:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-05T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-05T14:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-05T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-06T02:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-06T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-06T14:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-06T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-07T02:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-07T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-07T14:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-07T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-08T02:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-08T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-08T14:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-08T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
</time-layout>
<time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
  <layout-key>k-p3h-n19-2</layout-key>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-02T14:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-02T17:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-02T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-02T23:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T02:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T05:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T11:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T14:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T17:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-03T23:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-04T02:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-04T05:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-04T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-04T11:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-04T14:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-04T17:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
  <start-valid-time>2015-10-04T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
</time-layout>
<parameters applicable-location="point1">
  <temperature type="hourly" units="Celsius" time-layout="k-p3h-n35-1">
    <name>Temperature</name>
    <value>23</value>
    <value>23</value>
    <value>21</value>
    <value>20</value>
    <value>19</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>23</value>
    <value>26</value>
    <value>25</value>
    <value>22</value>
    <value>21</value>
    <value>20</value>
    <value>19</value>
    <value>19</value>
    <value>24</value>
    <value>26</value>
    <value>26</value>
    <value>22</value>
    <value>19</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>27</value>
    <value>23</value>
    <value>21</value>
    <value>19</value>
    <value>27</value>
    <value>23</value>
    <value>21</value>
    <value>20</value>
    <value>27</value>
    <value>24</value>
    <value>22</value>
    <value>21</value>
    <value>28</value>
    <value>24</value>
  </temperature>
  <temperature type="dew point" units="Celsius" time-layout="k-p3h-n35-1">
    <name>Dew Point Temperature</name>
    <value>20</value>
    <value>20</value>
    <value>19</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>17</value>
    <value>17</value>
    <value>17</value>
    <value>17</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>17</value>
    <value>17</value>
    <value>17</value>
    <value>17</value>
    <value>17</value>
    <value>17</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>19</value>
    <value>19</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>19</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>18</value>
    <value>19</value>
    <value>19</value>
    <value>19</value>
    <value>19</value>
    <value>19</value>
    <value>20</value>
  </temperature>
  <wind-speed type="sustained" units="meters/second" time-layout="k-p3h-n35-1">
    <name>Wind Speed</name>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>3</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>3</value>
    <value>3</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>3</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>3</value>
    <value>4</value>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>4</value>
  </wind-speed>
  <direction type="wind" units="degrees true" time-layout="k-p3h-n35-1">
    <name>Wind Direction</name>
    <value>0</value>
    <value>360</value>
    <value>340</value>
    <value>340</value>
    <value>320</value>
    <value>310</value>
    <value>300</value>
    <value>280</value>
    <value>280</value>
    <value>270</value>
    <value>280</value>
    <value>280</value>
    <value>270</value>
    <value>260</value>
    <value>240</value>
    <value>250</value>
    <value>250</value>
    <value>240</value>
    <value>240</value>
    <value>260</value>
    <value>300</value>
    <value>350</value>
    <value>360</value>
    <value>350</value>
    <value>350</value>
    <value>10</value>
    <value>10</value>
    <value>20</value>
    <value>10</value>
    <value>30</value>
    <value>40</value>
    <value>40</value>
    <value>40</value>
    <value>60</value>
    <value>60</value>
  </direction>
  <cloud-amount type="total" units="percent" time-layout="k-p3h-n35-1">
    <name>Cloud Cover Amount</name>
    <value>100</value>
    <value>100</value>
    <value>100</value>
    <value>99</value>
    <value>97</value>
    <value>90</value>
    <value>79</value>
    <value>71</value>
    <value>64</value>
    <value>72</value>
    <value>79</value>
    <value>78</value>
    <value>76</value>
    <value>72</value>
    <value>69</value>
    <value>69</value>
    <value>51</value>
    <value>51</value>
    <value>35</value>
    <value>28</value>
    <value>64</value>
    <value>63</value>
    <value>63</value>
    <value>62</value>
    <value>62</value>
    <value>60</value>
    <value>48</value>
    <value>37</value>
    <value>32</value>
    <value>35</value>
    <value>37</value>
    <value>41</value>
    <value>45</value>
    <value>40</value>
    <value>31</value>
  </cloud-amount>
  <wind-speed type="gust" units="meters/second" time-layout="k-p3h-n19-2">
    <name>Wind Speed Gust</name>
    <value>7</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>7</value>
    <value>7</value>
    <value>7</value>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>4</value>
  </wind-speed>
  <weather time-layout="k-p3h-n35-1">
    <name>Weather Type, Coverage, and Intensity</name>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="moderate" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="moderate" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="moderate" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="moderate" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="chance" intensity="moderate" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="chance" intensity="moderate" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="moderate" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="moderate" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="chance" intensity="moderate" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="none" additive="and" weather-type="thunderstorms" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="chance" intensity="moderate" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="none" additive="and" weather-type="thunderstorms" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="none" additive="and" weather-type="thunderstorms" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions>
      <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
      </value>
    </weather-conditions>
    <weather-conditions/>
    <weather-conditions/>
    <weather-conditions/>
    <weather-conditions/>
    <weather-conditions/>
    <weather-conditions/>
    <weather-conditions/>
    <weather-conditions/>
    <weather-conditions/>
  </weather>
</parameters>
```

Comment: You'll probably get better results with another approach to xml parsing.

Comment: How is your data structure being generated?

Comment: That looks like `XML::Simple` has been vandalising it.

Comment: The return from `Data::Dumper` is a string. It is good for visualizing data structures but you would want to access the elements of the data structure itself, not through `Data::Dumper`.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the perl script itself.

Comment: I'd suggest turning on `use strict;` `use warnings;`. But also - could you `print $value` and update the question with the output? I think that should be some raw, unparsed XML, which'll help me give you an answer that works.

Comment: Hah: `use XML::Simple;` -> from http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BLACKWIND/NDFD-Weather-Report/lib/NDFD/Weather/Report.pm

Comment: I was able to come up with a better solution with some slightly different syntax:  $result=XML::Simple->new()->XMLin($value)   Then    Dumper($result);  returned something I could use.  I'm now getting all the values properly.   Thanks for all the help/ideas!

Comment: It'll work, but seriously - don't. `XML::Simple` recommends not using `XML::Simple`. I would suggest reposting an XML parsing question for extracting the data you desire - there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using `XML::Parser->new(Style => 'Tree')`. This parser's interface is rather simplistic, which is a nice way to say it's not very user-friendly. You can figure out how to do it by counting the brackets:

```
$VAR -> [2][0][2][0][1]{'srsName'};
```

But seriously, there are far friendlier options. Just use `XML::Twig` or `XML::LibXML` because then the above becomes:

```
 $twig -> findnodes('//srsName',0)->trimmed_text;
```

(or something similar - like I say, give us some XML and we can give you an exact answer).

Edit:

Like this (NB: Untested, because I can't get that module to download):

```
 use XML::Twig; 

 my $value= $result->LatLonListCityNames;
 my $twig = XML::Twig -> parse ( $value ); 

 my $srsName_element = $twig -> findnodes ( '//srsName', 0 );
 $srsName_element -> print;
 print $srsName_element -> trimmed_text;
```

Comment: I've updated the question to include the perl script itself.

Comment: Edited my answer. Would be useful if you could run `print $value;` and add the XML to your question, just so I can test it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having trouble is because `[` means that the data is contained in an array reference, not a hash reference, so it must be accessed differently.

Lets try and break this down (replacing all the contents with placeholders)

```
$VAR1 = [
          0 (string),
          1 (hash  ),
      --> 2 (array ) [
                   --> 0 (array) [
                                   0 (string),
                                   1 (hash  ),
                               --> 2 (array ) [
                                            --> 0 (array) [
                                                            0 (string )
                                                        --> 1 (hash   ) {
                                                                      --> 'srsName' => $val
```

Simply follow the `-->`'s.  Each one points to the next element you must access to traverse the data structure.

I have not tested this, but it appears that it can be accessed through

`my $srsName = $xml_handler1->[2][0][2][0][1]{'srsName'};`

As many others have said though, using `Data::Dumper` and manually accessing the data is clearly not a good way to parse XML.  I personally am not familiar with the "proper" methods you should use to do this, but I suggest you read the comments and take a look at Sobrique's answer.

---

On a side note...  You should **ALWAYS** add `use strict` and `use warnings` to the top of your scripts and define all variables lexically using `my`.  It prevents bad coding habits and can save you a lot of headaches trying to debug code with hard to find problems.

For a list of reasons why check out this [article](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=111088).

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  It was actually very helpful in finding how to get to those values.  But I ended up finding a better solution:   $result=XML::Simple->new()->XMLin($value) Then Dumper($result); returned something I could use.